# How to resize a column in a astropy.io.fits BinTableHDU

Tags: python, astropy, fits

I'm attempting to resize a column in a FITS BinTableHDU column after it has been created, but I can't seem to find a way to do this in the astropy documentation.

For example, suppose a simple fits file was created with a BinTableHDU containing a single column of length 3:

```
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.table import Table
import numpy as np

hdul = fits.HDUList()
hdul.append(fits.PrimaryHDU())
data = Table({'test':[42,42,42]})
hdul.append(fits.BinTableHDU(data))

hdul.writeto('test.fits', overwrite=True)
```

And then later, I want to reopen the file, change the column and save it out to a new file:

```
hdul = fits.open('test.fits')
hdul[1].data['test'] = np.array([27, 27])
hdul.writeto('new_test.fits', overwrite=True)
```

My hope was, that by replacing the column with a new numpy array instance, that it would overwrite the old one.  But I get the following error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,) into shape (3,)
```

That error is not too surprising, given the difference in dimensions, but I'm looking for a way to completely replace the column, or otherwise change its shape.

Things to note, the column is of type numpy.ndarray:

```
col_data = hdul[1].data['test']
print(type(col_data))
print(col_data)
```

which shows:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[42 42 42]
```

However, the usual method for resizing the array doesn't seem to work:

```
hdul[1].data['test'].resize((2,))
```

throws:

```
ValueError: cannot resize this array: it does not own its data
```

Other strange behavior.  If I try to replace it with a single element array, rather than throwing an error, it replaces every element with the scalar:

```
hdul[1].data['test'] = np.array([27])
print(col_data)
```

shows:

```
[27 27 27]
```

I realize that one may point out that I should just change the original dimensions of the column as it is created.  But in my particular use case, I need to modify it after the creation of the BinTableHDU. That's what I'm trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Create a completely new BinTableHDU with the new data, and replace the old one in your HDU list. Does that not work?

Comment: That's a fair point, and should likely work.  However, it may consume more memory during the operation I suspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Easy way to update binary table data with different size in a FITS file

In the example from the question, only one table column needs to be updated and with a different size. The `Table` class has a `replace_column` function to help with this.

```
hdul = fits.open('test.fits')
table = Table(hdul[1].data)
table.replace_column('test', [27, 27])
hdul[1] = fits.BinTableHDU(table)
hdul.writeto('new_test.fits', overwrite=True)
```

However, this is a little complicated if multiple columns are involved. In the standard `BinTableHDU` implemented by `astropy`, all columns must be the same size. In order to use variable length columns special special keywords must be used. See astropy tutorial [here](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/usage/unfamiliar.html#variable-length-array-tables). That being said, as long as columns are being replaced with arrays of the same size the code above should be OK.

**When replacing an element with a single element array, rather than throwing an error, it replaces every element with the scalar.**

As mentioned above, the standard type of `FITS` `BinaryTable` supported by `astropy` is non-variable length. Therefore, one behavior `astropy` has implemented for your convenience is to broadcast scalars into the array. While the broadcast doesn't seem like the right behavior for a single column table, my guess is this behavior is overriding the expected behavior. See table examples from [quick overview](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/table/modify_table.html#quick-overview). *"A single column can be added to a table using syntax like adding a key-value pair to a dict. The value on the right hand side can be a list or numpy.ndarray of the correct size, or a scalar value that will be broadcast"*.

Comment: Thanks!  That does the trick.  I knew there had to be some way to do that.  That works perfectly.